# Any way to validate pig script before running in hdfs cluster?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm new to pig script. The problem I'm facing is inability to validate how syntactically correct my script is. I have to upload it to hdfs cluster and run there just to realize I missed ';' in the end of the line. Big waste of time. I use IntelliJ IDEA with pig script plugin, but while it helps to highlight pig statements it does not validate it.  Apache Pig does not seem to have any compiler, you can only run it, but I can't run it locally, data is not available from my laptop. So I wonder it there is any sophisticated pig script syntax validator, so I can run it and check if my script syntactically correct before uploading to the server.

Comment: Leverage `dump` at successive steps.

Comment: sorry, I do not get it. could you please elaborate?

Comment: I meant you could leverage `Dump` operator for debugging Purpose. The statements are executed immediately and the results are not saved (persisted). However the same is not recommended for production scripts as it will disable multi-query optimizations and slow down overall execution. Refer to the doc : https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/test.html for more clarity on testing and diagnostics.